# ASP.NET MVC 4 IE8/IE10 POST FORM (Boostrap.css) compatibility issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-10

I've been working on an application that uses ASP.NET MVC 4 with the bootstrap CSS. My application needs to be compatible with IE8 and IE10.. I have 8 @Html.textboxFors which represent a search model on my index page. When I press the search button it passes back the value from each of these boxes which gets appended to a dynamic where clause. This where clause then gets sent to a database procedure and returns back results. In IE10 this application works fine, if the textbox is left empty it just doesn't get added to the where clause and we can search with only inputting 1 text box. In IE8 I **NEED** to have text in each textbox for it to work. It will not post unless all of my textboxes are filled in. Any thoughts? If this is a terrible description just ask me more questions and I will try and explain as best as possible.. Thank you for your help.

Resolved********************

I was using a version of Jquery that was not compatible with IE10

Comment: I think you need to show some code, what your describing does not really make sense and I suspect it has nothing to do with bootstrap.

Comment: is the action using if(ModelState.Valid())?

Comment: I added the controller code, and I agree... its not with bootstrap but its just so odd to me that it works fine in IE10 but in IE8 it wont post unless